# Rails 3.0 Model/Controller Design Question

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :hosts, :dependent => :destroy
end

class Host < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :client_id, :host, :is_embedded, :gmaps_key
  belongs_to :client
end
```

As you can tell by the above code a client can have many hosts. I am trying to figure out how to design my controller for hosts. The end goal is to have multiple "index" pages that show the hosts for each Client. I don't need a page to show all the hosts. How would you recommend setting this up? Should I do nested routing?

```
resources :clients do
  resources :hosts
end
```

Comment: You have outlined no reason why nested routing would not be fine, but a hosts collection for client would be fine too

Comment: If you don't want to do nested routing, you can allays send extra GET parameters used for filtering `?client=1` or `?search[client]=1` etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds to me like your best option is nested routing - at least for the host index pages. If you wanted to not have the entire hosts resources nested underneath clients, then you could nest the index action only. For example:

```
resources :clients do
  resources :hosts, :only => [:index]
end

resources :hosts, :except => [:index]
```

This would mean that in your HostsController the client_id parameter would only be present in the index action. All other actions would only have an id parameter for the host. You would then view all hosts for a client using a URL like this:

```
http://localhost:3000/clients/10/hosts
```

And you would view info on an individual host like this:

```
http://localhost:3000/hosts/291
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a simple nested route like the one you suggest would be perfect for this. You will want to modify your `HostsController` to load only the hosts for the client specified though:

```
# in app/controllers/hosts_controller.rb
def index
  @hosts = Client.find(params[:client_id]).all
end
```

And you can access that page via http://example.com/clients/1/hosts. Pretty straightforward, no?